# Which extensions in Visual Studio Code should I use for Typo3 (syntax highlighting, recognizing keywords, auto-completion, ...)

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, typo3, syntax-highlighting

**It's a crux:** just one letter in lower case instead of upper case, a missing bracket, a tiny typo, and nothing works anymore **without a message** from the Typo3 backend.

It would also be of great help if key words in the configuration language were highlighted in color and thus distinguishable from your own terms.

And of course auto-complete would be great!

Which extensions can help and are recommended?

Comment: As most of the TYPO3 community is using PHP-Storm your highlighter of (missing keyword:) `TypoScript` exists as a plugin for PHP-Storm. On the other hand there is a highlighter in the TYPO3 backend: if you work in the template module and edit the setup or constant part seperatly you get support from the build in editor. I don't know of plugins for other editors.

Comment: All you need is available in PhpStorm with plugins as Bernd already mentioned, on the one hand, both things are paid (can be used/tested for free for some time, which I'd suggest). After the trial period you can use it with a time limit, or buy which is a good option when using for professional things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching in the Extension Marketplace inside Visual Studio Code "TypoScript" shows the extension `vscode-typo3-typoscript` by Benjamin Kott. He's also a [repository](https://github.com/benjaminkott/vscode-typo3-typoscript) for it, which is also linked in that extension.
The last update is already some time ago and it should likely be updated.

There is still another `TypoScript` extension but the last update is longer time ago than of that above.

As you never wrote TypoScript but TYPO3 in general:
There is also an extension with Code Snippets for TYPO3, the identifier is `ralffreit.typo3snippets` and it's shown as "TYPO3 Code Snippets".